# How to disable submit button if the form input has the same value - jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form inputs which are `msgid` is unique in every `group name`. User can input the same msgid as long as it has different `group name`, if it has the same `msgid` and `group name` submit button will be disabled. this is my form https://jsfiddle.net/qd1jb0p4/1/

correct example input.

```
group_name: electrical
msgid: pliers

group_name: mechanical
msgid: pliers

group_name: 
msgid: gaming
```

incorrect example input, and this time I want to disable the submit button.

```
group_name: electrical
msgid: pliers

group_name: electrical
msgid: pliers

group_name: 
msgid: gaming
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to distinguish the form elements somehow, and I chose to separate each set with a `.form-group`. This is using a blur event, but if you wanted something more interactive, swap `'blur'` for `'input'`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-item input').on('blur', checkForm)
  checkForm()
})

function checkForm() {
  let test = []
  $('.form-group').each(function() {
    let item = $(this).find('input[type=text]').map((_, el) => el.value).get()
    test.push(item.join(''));
  });
  test = test.filter(e => e)
  if (test.length != [...new Set(test)].length) $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  else $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for="" class="form-control">Group Name</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Group name...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for="" class="form-control">msgid</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for="" class="form-control">Group Name</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Group name...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for="" class="form-control">msgid</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for="" class="form-control">Group Name</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Group name...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-item">
    <label for=""  class="form-control">msgid</label>
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way that I could get the error value? because in some point I will create an alert message and display the error input value and also highlight the input field. Sorry to bother but I didn't mention that the fields are dynamic, that there is an ADD MORE button to create more input fields (group name and msgid) 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Attach a `change` event handler to the group and msgid text fields
Let the event handler check if for duplicate values
When there are duplicates set the disabled property of the submit button to true
When there are no duplicates set the disabled property of the submit button to false

Comment: unless I am misunderstanding, there can be duplicate fields, but not duplicate groups